# Getx did not clear the previous views after doing log out

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I do log out and then log in with another user but I find that the profile page and other pages are still on the same view before logging out to the previous user

I used

```
Get.offAllNamed('/pageName');
```

and

```
Get.deletAll();
```

and

```
Get.delete<controller>();
```

and

```
 Get.offUntil(GetPageRoute(page: () => DirectionScreen()), ModalRoute.withName('/direct') );
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 300), ()=>Get.delete<PageNavigationController>());
```

and

```
  Navigator.of(context)
            .pushAndRemoveUntil(
          CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DirectionScreen()
          ),
              (_) => false,
        );
```

and flutter_phoenix package

```
Phoenix.rebirth(Get.context!);
```

and path_provider package.

nothing do the work

Comment: please provide code snippet when you login and logout

Answer (score 0):

I use [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app/example) package and its do the work